# Hover css slide out for multiple objects/items

Tags: html, css

I am doing a website project and I would like to have this cool hover effect but I can't seem to get it to work right?

I have a vinyl record case image that slides to the left with a title (overflow:hidden) to reveal the record image behind it. At the same time from the left I want a description of the record to slid out from behind the vinly record case thats moving to the left and be on top of the record image with a little opacity so you can still see the record(this part is easy)

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="stations">
<div class="grid_3">
<div class="records"><!-- sleeve -->
<h3>Groove Salad</h3>
<div class="recordsinfo">Station description.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the css code:

```
#stations>div {
background-image: url(http://benlevywebdesign.com/somafm/images/SomaFMrecord.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height: 220px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

#stations>div>.records{
background-image: url(http://benlevywebdesign.com/somafm/images/SomaFM.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height: 220px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

#stations>div>.records>h3 {
color: #FFF;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.45);
width:200px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:-5px;
padding: 10px 10px 3px;
}

#stations>div>.records>.recordsinfo{
position: absolute;
left:-150px;
bottom: 0;
margin: 5px 10px;
}

@-moz-keyframes slideout {
    0% { left:0; }
    100% { left:-100px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideout {
    0% { left:0; }
    100% { left:-100px; }
}
@keyframes slideout {
    0% { left:0; }
    100% { left:-100px; }
}


#stations>div>.records:hover{
height: 220px;
width:220%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
left:-100px;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
-moz-animation: slideout 0.75s 1;
-webkit-animation: slideout 0.75s 1;
animation: slideout 0.75s 1;
}

#stations>div>.records>.recordsinfo:hover{
height: 220px;
width:220%;
left:150px;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
-moz-animation: slidein 0.75s 1;
-webkit-animation: slidein 0.75s 1;
animation: slidein 0.75s 1;
}
```

and here is a fiddle of it working up until the last part which is the description not working and sliding out left!

*Updated fiddle*
http://jsfiddle.net/Xc9U6/11/

Comment: Should this code (html & css) all be in the html file?
That's what i did and it works, everything ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uK3mr/)

***HTML***

```
<div id="stations">
    <div class="grid_3">
        <div class="records"><!-- sleeve -->
            <h3>Groove Salad</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="recordsinfo">Station description.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
#stations > div {
    background-image: url(http://benlevywebdesign.com/somafm/images/SomaFMrecord.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 220px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#stations > div:hover .records {
    margin-left: -110px;
}

#stations .records{
    background-image: url(http://benlevywebdesign.com/somafm/images/SomaFM.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;

    -webkit-transition: all .75s;
       -moz-transition: all .75s;
            transition: all .75s;
}

#stations h3 {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.45);
    width:200px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
    padding: 10px 10px 3px;
}

#stations > div:hover .recordsinfo {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#stations .recordsinfo {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px -150px;

    -webkit-transition: all .75s;
       -moz-transition: all .75s;
            transition: all .75s;
}
```

Comment: what happened to my keyframes?

Comment: I thought it's an overkill here and replaced with some simpler transitions, just to make the code shorter and cleaner

Comment: Ok it works but the description is not moving out far enough check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xc9U6/13/

Comment: I made a small change to your HTML as well, but if you want to go with your original one you have to add the `110px` you're moving your cover to the left to the description margin - http://jsfiddle.net/Xc9U6/14/

Comment: I don't see what you changed in my html?

Comment: moved `.recordsinfo` outside of `.records`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17517/discussion-between-benlevywebdesign-and-zoltan-toth)

Comment: what does the "all" do on the transition

Comment: `all` means animate **all** the properties you're changing - in your case it's just the margin, so you could write `transition: margin-left .75s`

Comment: then that would make them separate and is there another way to chat with you because I don't want to right an whole new question for something when you seem like you could answer it!

Comment: do you have a GTalk/Google acc?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you want the title to remain where it is? if so here you go:

```
#stations > div > .records:hover h3 {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Not quite? I want the description of the record to slide out from the left underneath the vinyl case that is moving left

Comment: And still remain on the cover or beneath it and have a background so you can read it?

Comment: Currently the title goes with the vinyl case and that's what I want to happen. At the same time as the vinyl case is moving left, from behind it i want a description to slide out right

Comment: `#stations > div > .records:hover recordsinfo {
    left:100; /* if you want it to be place on the case,or bigger with a background if you want it outside*/
}`

Answer (score 0):

Finally!  You had lots of different issues here, from setting a width of 220%, instead of px, To trying to animate a child of an animation (so it's positions were off), to not defining the slidein animation you wanted to use.

Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc9U6/12/)